# setInterval causes memory-leak

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, setinterval

We have obviously done something wrong in our code, but we can't seem to understand what. If we want to fetch a file within a specific interval, how come we can't use this code?

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        let interval = 2

        function fetchSource(source) {
            fetch(source, { cache: 'no-cache' })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('Memory-bloating')
                })
        }

        function test() {
            fetchSource('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/LARGE_elevation.jpg')
        }

        setInterval(test, interval * 1000)
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Memory-bloating in chrome
</body>

</html>
```

The problem here is that every time we fetch, we increase our memory with the size of the image, and it never seems get garbage collected. When the site has been up for about 2-3 hours, we've filled our computer with this image.

How should we build this function to not have this rather huge memory leak?

Comment: I expect the leak is in the `fetch()` function itself, which you have not included.

Comment: "I expect the leak is in the fetch() function itself, which you have not included. " @Alnitak i assume fetch is a native javascript function here in this question.

Comment: @RaymondNijland exactly. If you run this html-file in your browser, your browser have fetch-support and setInterval-support. Myself, I run Chrome on MacOS. I guess (and hope) they implemented:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: By the way can't you use the browser plugins or native javascript performance api's to get a better idea on which part off the code is the memory leak?

Comment: Actually, when using chromes memory-tool you get that the site only takes a few MB, while chromes task-manager tells you that it takes a few GB.

Comment: @RaymondNijland ah, thanks!   That's a new one to me.  Even so, my comment still stands - there's no code I can see here that ought to create a leak.

Comment: "Even so, my comment still stands - there's no code I can see here that ought to create a leak" @Alnitak you sure? setInterval and using closures in javascript can cause leaks

Comment: What is interesting is that in the "Performance" tab you can see the memory (JS Heap) increase each time the fetch is executed. But once you go to memory tab and take heap snapshots you can't see the increase! Looks like a Chrome bug to me!

Comment: @RaymondNijland not 100% sure, no, but the only closure here is the `.then` callback which retains no variables from any outer scope.

Comment: Testing your code in Chrome Canary (v.71) and checking the performance and memory evolution I can clearly see when the garbage collector enters and do its job, with the code you have provided, even if you are using the potentially problematic `setInterval`.

Comment: not sure if fetch is a return function so it possible to do this `var fetch = fetch(...); fetch = null;` and might force the browser to clean the memory..

Comment: @RaymondNijland unfortunately setting fetch to null doesn't resolve the issue either.

Comment: NB: functions that generate Promises  should _always_ `return` that promise so that other functions can chain from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this will stop :

```
   let interval = 2
   let handle = ""
   let still_fetching = false

       function fetchSource(source) {
           fetch(source, { cache: 'no-cache' })
               .then(response => {
                   console.log('Memory-bloating')
                   clearInterval(handle)
                   still_fetching = false
                   handle = null
                   handle = setInterval(test, interval * 1000)
               })
       }

       function test() {
           if(still_fetching){
               return;
           }
           still_fetching = true;
           fetchSource('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/LARGE_elevation.jpg')
       }

       handle = setInterval(test, interval * 1000)
```

Comment: If you can, it's worth explaining *how* you have solved the problem as well as providing the code.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this actually does solve the problem.   The state being retained here only serves to ensure that there are no concurrent fetches in progress.   It effectively turns the `setInterval` call into a `setTimeout` call because the interval timer is only permitted to fire once per download.  It also introduces an unnecessary circular dependency between `fetchSource` and `test`, which breaks the separation of concerns between these functions.

Comment: So, this works better, but it seems to still slow down my application quite a bit. When running it start garbage collecting every now and then, but it still reaches over a few gigabytes quite fast (3-5 minutes to reach 1 gigabyte). Is it just that chrome isn't good enough at garbage collecting, or is this some issue with the implementation? 10 minutes in now and 2.5GB.

Comment: If I manually press "Collect garbage" at the Memory-screen, it goes down to 50 MB again.

Comment: @Alnitak you are certainly right. This will have a circular dependency, something I would rather much appreciate if I could do without. I'll look into if it's a chrome-issue (which potentially is resolved in Canary v71).

Answer (score 0):

Posting here, because the code is too long for a comment.   I think this is probably a Chrome bug, but by preventing concurrent downloads you may be able to confirm that.

The following is a cleaner equivalent to @McBern's code that removes the circular dependency and the need to maintain additional state:

```
let interval = 2

function fetchSource(source) {
    return fetch(source, { cache: 'no-cache' })  // NB: return
          .then(response => {
               console.log('Memory-bloating')
           })
    }
}

(function test() {
   let url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/LARGE_elevation.jpg';

   fetchSource(url).then(() => setTimeout(test, interval * 1000));
})();
```

Comment: Concurrent downloading is not the problem, since we normally only download a file of ca 13MB every 5 minutes, and if the computer is on for say 15-20 days, the tab has grown to over 10GB. I have just made this example to make it easier for you to help me understand the issue.

Comment: @user2687506 fair enough - you said that the other code "worked better" although the only major change was that he resets (and recreates) the interval timer after each download.   It would be interesting to know whether this version also "works better".

Comment: Alnitak you are right. I might have jumped the gun on his code being better. It garbage collected twice, and then stopped, so it might be Chrome who cleaned up some garbage from before reloading the page.

Your version of the code did, unfortunately, not work better than his. It's far more pretty and if it would've been a solution yours is the one I would've chosen, but as I said, the garbage collection doesn't kick in with this code either. Thank you for your help though! :)